# Centering a div horizontally with variable width not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I practiced to center a div without a width and found a solution that works in every common browser. But when I put this solution into real page style, it wont work in IE.

The practice solution, that works perfectly in IE, Chrome and Firefox, looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Centerbox</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="centerbox.css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="centerbox-outer">
        <div class="centerbox-inner">
            <p>Sample content that is not fixed width</p>
            <p>Some more content</p>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="sampleinput" />
                <input type="submit" name="go" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

centerbox.css

```
div.centerbox-outer{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.centerbox-inner{
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The page where it is not working with IE is here: [link removed]

Do someone have any idea, what I'm missing there?

Comment: Which version of IE is working? And which isn't? IE6 doesn't work, and neither does IE7. In both cases, the grey box (in the sample) is the full width of the viewport.

Comment: I'v tried with IE8, haven't tried with older ones, but you gave me a good hint. I'm using <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/> for the page, that's why it is different. But how can i fix this in IE7 using CSS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Made some research and found a suitable solution using relative positions. This seem to work perfectly in commonly used browsers.

The style would be following:

```
div.centerbox-outer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

div.centerbox-inner{
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in FF 10.0.2 (linux)  Works in chrome though

Answer (score 0):

To center a div, use:

```
 margin-left: auto; 
 margin-right: auto;
```

in the css for the div.  Also, I've found for IE, you may need to alter your DocType to an HTML 4 specification.  Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

I do these in my pages, and they center perfectly in IE.

Answer (score 0):

`div.centerbox-outer` is 100% width, so putting `margin: 0 auto;` on it does not make any sense. If anything, you should put `margin: 0 auto;` on `div.centerbox-inner`.

Comment: Ok, made the changes, but still no luck