# CSS - How to center a div of variable height and width in the center of another div?

Tags: css

I have come across some methods of centering a div within a div, but those usually requires the element to be centered to have a fixed width and height. Is there a way to do it if the inner div to be centered will be of variable width and height (example: centering an image inside a frame of a fixed size, and the image could be of variable width/height)

Answer (score 2):

horizontal centering can be done with CSS:

```
#containerDiv {
  text-align:center;
}

#innerDiv {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

For vertical centering I use Javascript if the containerDiv doesn't have a fixed height.

Comment: Note: this won't work on block-level elements without setting a fixed width on the inner container. If you don't know the width of the inner container, set it to display: inline-block and it will be centered properly. The other alternative (if you're not a fan of inline-block) is to use [the technique documented here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206735/centering-a-div-horizontally-with-variable-width-not-working-in-ie/3207432#3207432).

Answer (score 1):

The only ways to center variable width *in all browsers* (that I know of) is with

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><div>This div is variable width and is centered.</div></td></tr></table>
```

or JavaScript

As for center horizontal that would force you to use JavaScript (I think)

Answer (score 1):

IE needs a "text-align: center" on the top-level element.

For example, your body element has "text-align: center",
and your container has "margin: 0 auto".
Then IE will center it.

You can set back "text-align" to left on your container if you don't want its content centered.

Answer (score 0):

Centering the width is easy...you probably already know this, but just set the left and right margin to auto.  For height, unfortunately, I've only seen weird positioning work-arounds.  You'd think that they'd make a similar margin for top/bottom, but alas, no.  I'll try to find a link on the work-arounds.

```
<div style='width:400px;height:200px;background-color:#CCCCCC;'>
    <div style='margin:0px auto;width:30px;height:30px;background-color:#0000CC;'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Found link that might help on the vertical part:

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: Honestly, as much as I like doing css positioning and avoiding tables, when I need something to be vertically aligned in the middle, I still use tables even for non-tabular data rather than the CSS positioning fixes like the link I posted.

Comment: Based on my experience, this doesn't work for IE. IE ignores margin auto setting, and put element at left side. Any comment?

Comment: What's your DOCTYPE?  The above example works fine with XHTML transitional: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Also works in IE for XHTML strict, HTML 4.0 transitional, and HTML 5.  I can only get it to go to the left by removing the DOCTYPE completely...are you using a DOCTYPE at all?  IE is picky about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the display attribute [to make a table-cell out of it](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html):

```
DIV.container {
    min-height: 10em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle }
...
<DIV class="container">
  <P>This small paragraph...
</DIV>
```

However, this recommendation does not really work for me. But this one does:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6284195/156481