# How can I make a postion: absolute; dialog initially appear within the viewport no matter where the page is scrolled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a dialog `div` appear within the viewport every time it is shown without using `position: fixed;`. Essentially when the *Show* buttons in the below example are clicked, I want the dialog to appear where it would if its position were fixed, but I want its position to be absolute. Or, in slightly different words, I "... want it to be positioned *as if it were fixed*, and then *stop being fixed immediately after placement*." (Thanks [apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170770/how-can-i-make-a-postion-absolute-dialog-appear-within-the-viewport-no-matter#comment-48447886)) I want it to be `position: absolute;` so that I can still scroll past it in the browser, but I still want it to appear in the viewport when it is initially shown.

I've tried a lot of different CSS from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764399/how-to-position-the-div-popup-dialog-to-the-center-of-browser-screen), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758102/how-do-i-horizontally-center-an-absolute-positioned-element-inside-a-100-width), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042467/css-displayinline-block-and-positioningabsolute), but none seemed to fulfill my requirements. Note that I cannot use JQuery or other JS libraries.

```css
.dialog {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="dialog" class="dialog" style="display:none;">Dialog</div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('dialog').style.display=null;">Show</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('dialog').style.display=null;">Show</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('dialog').style.display=null;">Show</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('dialog').style.display=null;">Show</button>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried using the `<dialog>` element yet only chrome and opera support it:

Comment: I'm curious as to the reason for this question.. I feel like asking for it to "appear where it would if it's position were fixed, but I want it's position to be absolute" is kind of like asking for a way for text to appear green, even though it is set to `color: blue;`. Why does it need to be `absolute`?

Comment: Wait, so you want it to be positioned *as if it were fixed*, and then *stop being fixed* immediately after placement, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use absolute positioned dialog with scroll position tracking.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
     var body = document.body;
     var top = body.scrollTop || body.parentElement.scrollTop;
     document.getElementById('#yourPoupUp').style.top = top + 'px';
});
```

(Add also the same handler using `document.attachEvent()` in case you need old IE support)

But I wouldn't recommend this way. Use `position:fixed` if it is possible.

Comment: Nice answer! For my specific example, I only need to run this code in the `onclick` of any buttons showing the dialog. I'm not sure, but it may be worth editing the example to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Take `<div id="dialog" class="dialog" style="display:none;">Dialog</div>`

and put it outside of any container divs so its only within the html & body elements.

add this css `html,body{position:relative;height:100%}`

and that should be you golden.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `position:fixed` instead of `absolute` or `relative`.

`position:fixed` means the element is positioned relative to the browser window.

---

**EDIT**

Didn't realise you said you DON'T want to do this, please explain why.