# Trying to center div horizontally and vertically in screen

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to make a div for my landing page of my website center in the very center of the screen, but it is not working.

Here is my code

CSS:

```
.centerDiv{
width:800px;
margin:0 auto;
border-radius: 5px;
background:#111;
padding:10px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="centerDiv" class="centerDiv">
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <p>Text will go here.</p>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Im not super worried about ie7 support, although ie8 would be nice.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> **Note:** If you're trying to center a div horizontally and vertically I would suggest looking into [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You'll still need to provide fallback support, but flexbox is the future and it's amazing.
>
> *Update: flexbox is supported by all [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) now.*

You need to give the div a static width and height first of all.

Second, you have to set `position: absolute;` and `left: 50%; top: 50%;` then you must do a `margin-left` and `margin-top` that are HALF of the height and width. It will then display correctly.

CSS:

```
.centerDiv{
  width: 800px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -400px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wJ7dY/

P.S. I changed your styling a bit so you could actually read the text. Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad it helped. Keep in mind if you add more text you'll need to adjust the `height:50px;` and `margin-top:-25px;` accordingly. Margin-top should **ALWAYS** be half of what the total height is! (Same with `width` and `margin-left`.)

Comment: +1 as works in IE7 and Compatibility View Mode.

Comment: If you dont want to fix a height and width and want your div to adapt to different screen sizes; here's an easier way to achieve this: [jsfiddle.net/NT8Mn](http://jsfiddle.net/NT8Mn)

Answer (score 17):

This code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PSZYn/)) allows for any `width` and `height` to be set, without having to update any other properties (e.g. `top` = `height / 2`) or relying on techniques that aren't well-supported (e.g. `display:table;`. The one downside is support for older IE versions is lacking. Combining this with another solution for IE only is probably you're best bet.

**The CSS:**

```css
.absoluteCenter {
 /* Must manually set width/height */
 width:800px;
 height:500px;

 /* The magic centering code */
 margin:auto;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;bottom:0; /* Aligns Vertically - Remove for Horizontal Only */
 left:0;right:0; /* Aligns Horizontally - Remove for Vertical Only  */

 /* Prevent div from overflowing main window */
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
 overflow:auto;
}

/* IE 7 and Below */
:first-child+html .absoluteCenter,
* html .absoluteCenter {
 /* Place code here to override all above values, and add IE friendly centering */
}
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<div class="absoluteCenter">
 Content of DIV
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll definitely keep this code saved. For the time being I'm going to use the static width/height just to be safe with older versions

Comment: *:first-child+html .absoluteCenter, * html .absoluteCenter {/* Static Code Here */} -- And you're welcome :)

Comment: did not work for me without static width/height. what I'm doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/2X6M2/1/

Comment: @Vitim.us You're absolutely right, I think I just explained this solution poorly (or wasn't in the right mind when I answered). Anyway, I've updated the answer with a more correct explanation and a few improvements (e.g. adds scrollbar if window is smaller than centered div). AFAIK, it's not possible (at least with current browsers) to have a fluid width/height `div` centered horizontally and vertically (although it [is possible with an `img`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6284195/526741)).

Comment: @bfrohs thanks anyway, I like css but I just can't understand the lack of centering content. like `box-align-vertical: middle;` `box-align-horizontal: center;` and `text-align-vertical: middle;` we're stuck with container tricks, tables, negative margins, line heights, etc... eww

Comment: this is the best answer.

Comment: the display: table & table-cell is much more modern. You should use that one.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. This option should vertically align the #center element in the #parent element regardless of the height of the #center element. I beleive you require a height on the #parent element though.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="center">
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <p>Text will go here.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent{
display: table;
width: /* Your width */;
height: /* Your height */;
}

#center{
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: /* Your width */;
height: /* Your height */;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I just used this yesterday, using `display:table` on the `body`. This technique should be [compatible through to IE8.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 .centerDiv{
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     height: 400px;
     margin-top: -200px; /* Half of the height */
     left: 50%;
     width:800px;
     margin-left: -400px; /* Half of the width */
     border-radius: 5px;
     background:#111;
     padding:10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

set margin to auto instead of 0 auto and you need a height. I think 100% for your purpose.