# Fixing center alignment with negative margin-left trick for small window

Tags: html, css

I have a div center-aligned that way:

```
<div id="container" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%; margin-left:-500px; width:1000px;"></div>
```

As this solution [Trying to center div horizontally and vertically in screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811427/trying-to-center-div-horizontally-and-vertically-in-screen) suggest.

The problem is that if the client's window's width (tried in FF 15.0.1)  is smaller than 1000px the horizontal scrollbar won't allow to show the left side of the div.

Is there a pure html/css way to solve it?

Comment: does it ALWAYS need to be 1000px? or can it be width:1000px;max-width:100%;?

Comment: yes it's necessary that it is always 1000px width.

Comment: then no. position:absolute; forces it to exactly what you tell it, and the body will not expand for the larger width so there is nowhere to scroll to.

Comment: I guess I'll have to use js for that...

Comment: i updated the code. Check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. You can not resize client window.
1 thing that you can do is avoid the left scroll setting the width of parent div to `1000px`

```
  <div id="parent" style="min-width:1000px;"> 
      <div id="container" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%;
        margin-left:-500px; width:1000px;"></div>
  </div>
```

**Note:** 
You might have to set the width of html and body tag to `min-width=100%`

**Updated:**

```
 <html style="min-width: 100%; background-color:Gray;">
 <body style="min-width: 100%; background-color:White;">
 <div id="parent" style="min-width: 1000px; position:relative;">
    <div id="container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 50%; margin-left: -500px;
        width: 1000px; border: 1px solid red; height: 10px;">
        1 2 3 4 5
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I missed `position:relative` to describe. This code is working.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html style="min-width:100%;">
<body style="min-width:100%;">
 <div id="parent" style="min-width:1000px;"> 
      <div id="container" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%;
        margin-left:-500px; width:1000px; border:1px solid red; height:10px;"> 1 2 3 4 5 </div>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>` Doesn't seem to produce the result...