# Center d3.js JavaScript Plot

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am working on a plot that is using the code from the example here:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118

I am new to HTML, CSS, and JS, but know some of the basics. I was wondering how I can center the plot in the browser's window, specifically what to put into the example code provided. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set margins left and right to auto, but you also need to make the element display as block-level.

```
svg {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This is better, but do you know how to center it vertically as well?

Comment: See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811427/trying-to-center-div-horizontally-and-vertically-in-screen).

Answer (score 0):

```
.plot
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

that will center it relatively in most browsers.

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Maybe it is conflicting with the margin variable?

Comment: Sorry can't account for everything with your particular build.