# Positioning image horizontally center and make height 100% of viewport

Tags: html, css

I have a an image taking up the entire height of the viewport. The image height should span the entire viewport height (100%) so that it will fit to the screen it is viewed from (already accomplished here) and the width should be relatively proportional to the height. As you can see in my page (http://lamininbeauty.co.za), the page has space on the sides. I want the image to center horizontally. Below is my code:

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main{
    margin: auto;
}

img.bg {
        /* Set rules to fill background */
        max-height: 100%;

        /* Set up proportionate scaling */
        height: auto;

        /* Set up positioning */
        position: fixed;

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <img class="bg" src="images/massage2.jpg" border="none" />  
</div>
</body>
```

Note: I do not want the image to lose aspect ratio and it should always fit in vertically 100%, none of the image being cut off and no vertical scrolling. Horizntal centering. I try to stay away from the background-size property since IE8 and lower does not support it.

Comment: Remember that there are no fixed widths, so 
position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 margin-left:-250px;
 margin-top:-250px; will not work (example sizes used)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply add `left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto;` to `img.bg` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/JnwWH/)):

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main{
    margin: auto;
}

img.bg {
    /* Set rules to fill background */
    max-height: 100%;

    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    height: auto;

    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;

    /* Align horizontally */
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;   
}
```

### Alternative Solution

If you want the image to never be cut off (horizontally or vertically), and always centered, try this code instead (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6284195/526741):

```
<img class="absoluteCenter" src="PATHTOIMAGE">
```

```css
/* Don't Change - Positioning */
.absoluteCenter {
 margin:auto;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}

/* Sizing */
img.absoluteCenter {
 max-height:100%;
 max-width:100%;
}
```

- [Wide image](http://jsfiddle.net/nzxPV/3/)
- [Tall image](http://jsfiddle.net/nzxPV/4/)
- [Small image](http://jsfiddle.net/nzxPV/5/)

Comment: @DextrousDave, no prob. See the additional solution I added from another answer of mine--I think it might be an even better solution for your needs :) (And don't forget to mark this *accept* this answer.)

Comment: As I asked Scot below, if i want to add text over that image, how would I go about that?

Comment: Your alternative answer is _sweet_! So good, I upvoted this and the one you linked too.

Comment: @DextrousDave, that is where things begin to get tricky. The `img` element handles size quite a bit differently from normal elements, which allows this absolute center trick to work in the first place. Achieving a similar affect with a different element (in current browsers) requires a static width and height on the wrapper element (or JavaScript). To do this, simply change `img.absoluteCenter` to the correct element and use `height` and `width` instead (these *can* be percentages). Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/nzxPV/6/).

Answer (score 1):

Put the img in a div and set `text-align: center`.  Make the div fixed, not the img.  To stretch smaller images, use `height: 100%` instead of `max-height`.

```
div.bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
div.bg img {
    height: 100%;
}​
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Mt7ce/

Comment: thanks a lot. This works just as good. If I wanted to add text on top of the image, how will I go about it?

Comment: Put a div containing the text inside the wrapper div and position it absolutely.

Comment: @DextrousDave - Here's an example of putting text on top of the image: http://jsfiddle.net/Mt7ce/1/.  A span works as well as a div: http://jsfiddle.net/Mt7ce/2/

Comment: thank you! Really nice code. I would have given you the points, but bfrohs above helped me first and he gave me multiple answers. But thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your `main` is going to contain other items, so with a second wrapper `div`:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="bg">
        <img src="http://lamininbeauty.co.za/images/massage2.jpg" border="none" />
        <span>Some text.</br>And Some More.</span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

You can set this css:

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
}

.bg img {
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.bg span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px; /* sizing this to the dynamic height of img will be a challenge */
    top: 20%;
}
```

And get what you want (with text now) [as shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/eujaH/17/). As noted, adding the text, the biggest challenge you are going to face is sizing that text. You will probably need to use javascript or an `@media` set to change text sizing with `height`. Personally, unless the text is vital (which I would think if this is background, it is not), I'd put the text in the image so that it scales with the size and stays right in relation to the image.

Comment: thanks man! this works great. One more question though, what if I want to add text over that image(say in a span tag), without disturbing the current layout?

Comment: @DextrousDave--added text overlay, though see my notes down out the bottom in my answer.

Comment: yeah, thanks. I also think putting the text inside the image is the safest bet

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if you can set the main height or not, but if you can set the height then

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main{
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
}

img.bg {
        /* Set rules to fill background */
        max-height: 100%;

        /* Set up proportionate scaling */
        height: auto;       
}
```

I only tested this on FF. For the height of main, you can always set it to the viewport with jquery. I was not able to come up with what you wanted without setting that height.

Comment: ok cool, thanks. I will see if there is anything else I can do, last resort I'll use jquery...but I don't want to fix the width for now. Thanks for your help

Comment: or else what I can do is, use media queries and set the height and width for each representative screen size...