# How to set max-height to image's original height in a responsive design?

Tags: responsive-design, css

I'm building a responsive site using WordPress, and images are automatically set to `height:100%; width:auto;` and the div resizes according to window size. But this often means some images have their height set to higher than their actual height causing pixelation. What i need is something like `height: 100%; width:auto; max-height:"image height here"`. How, if this is possible, is this possible?
The page where this is an issue is here: http://wheretoimmigrate.com/onthemouse/?portfolio=atomic-clothings-2012-campaign

Comment: [Something like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282968/vertical-centering-variable-height-image-while-maintaining-max-width-height/6284195#6284195)

Comment: nope, that doesn't work, but the second answer might be useful for me to set the enclosing divs height, hmm thanks i'll try to see if i can make that work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by simply making the images larger by adding a transparent background of larger size and different proportions. Tricked the system into treating it like a larger image. Worked perfectly.