# Vertical alignment of image in div

Tags: css, html, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vertical centering variable height image while maintaining max-width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282968/vertical-centering-variable-height-image-while-maintaining-max-width-height)

So here is a question, I've got image of not fixed size, I know only that the height or width must be 200px. Now I want to put this image in div which is fixed size 200px x 200px and center it vertically and horizontally. Is it possible?

I searched a lot of questions but none of them answered mine, which should be crushial to solve them all.

Comment: Height **or** width? How would it fit in the `div`?

Comment: Have you tried `text-align: center;` and `line-height: 200px`

Comment: Have you checked [this][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336503/how-to-vertical-align-image-inside-div

Let me know if that does not work.

Comment: dix is 200px x 200px, once image's width is 200px so I want it to be aligned vertically and once its height's 200px so I want to align it horizontally. All to be in center.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282968/vertical-centering-variable-height-image-while-maintaining-max-width-height/6284195#6284195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it display like a table cell:

http://jsbin.com/ijoved/1/

```
/* This is item wrapping each image */
.item { 
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: But one problem appears, why doesn't it work when the element is floating?

Comment: Floating an element make it `display: block` so the `display: table-cell;` is ignored

Comment: It should be noted that this technique isn't supported by IE7.

Answer (score 5):

Basic idea taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282968/vertical-centering-variable-height-image-while-maintaining-max-width-height/6284195#6284195). Doesn't rely on [`display:table-cell;`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) which isn't supported by IE7.

### The Code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsj64/))

```html
<div class="image-wrapper"><img src="http://example.com/image.png"></div>
```

```css
.image-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.image-wrapper img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```