# Horizontally center image larger than screen & shrink image on browser resize

Tags: javascript, css, image

Hello CSS guru's of stackoverflow.  I am stuck on a problem and I think perhaps it is just not possible with CSS.

I want to combine these two rules and apply them both to the same image:

1) dynamically scale image as browser size changes

```
#main-graphic {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

2) center image and crop sides of image as browser gets smaller

```
#main-graphic {
  width: 2560px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -1280px;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

But how do i do this with *just* CSS? Or is that not possible?

Comment: Yes, but that would still make it jumpy at each media query step. unless i used 1000 media queries.

Comment: You could use it for the switch between the two CSS. Or maybe I don't get what you want :).

Comment: You should be able to use something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282968/vertical-centering-variable-height-image-while-maintaining-max-width-height/6284195#6284195

Comment: bfrohs: that does not accomplish the cropping aspect, only the resizing aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make good use of Max/Min widths (and heights).

[Here is a good place to start.](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the image as a background-image on an empty div for example. I'm not entirely sure of how you want it, but something like this could suit your needs.

HTML

```
 <div class="img"></div>
```

CSS

```
.img {
    max-width: 2560px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('whatever.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting a width in your second code block I am assuming you don't want to resize the image.

This will keep the image centered regardless of page width and crop sides if the browser width doesn't accommodate for it...

```
#main-graphic {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('http://cux.waspdigital.com/wp-content/themes/creativeux/_/img/home-main.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 228px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1280px 228px;
  background-position: 50% 0;
}​

<div id="main-graphic"></div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xt2vM/

Comment: I do want the image to resize as well.  This jsfiddle only accomplishes #2 but not #1.